# Does Devtrack have an API that i could use with a chatbot ( slack )?

Tags: api, tracking, bots, slack

I want to build a chatbot  in Slack that can use some information that is stored in Devtrack.

For example  for the QA guys instead of receiving email notifications they could see them directly in the slack channel with the links to the problems.

Any advice or any information on how i could achieve something like this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any research done into this? Normally questions get answered the most if they show evidence of work and ideally not in the format of "how can I do this" but rather "i'm trying this and it doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

[Teambot](https://github.com/teambot-club/teambot) is an open source project with main goal to make development of Slack chatbots extremely easy. With few words this is a solution that works on nodejs and has architecture that makes your bot extremely extendable. You will be able to develop a skill for your bot that could accomplish the integration you need. I think you can also develop such an integration with let say Jenkins to be notified anytime particular job fails. I could help you with [Teambot](https://github.com/teambot-club/teambot) if you decided to give it a try.